# Find hashtags in string

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am working on a Xamarin.Forms PCL project in C# and would like to detect all the hashtags.

I tried splitting at spaces and checking if the word begins with an # but the problem is if the post contains two spaces like "Hello #World  Test" it would lose that the double space

```
string body = "Example string with a #hashtag in it";
        string newbody = "";
        foreach (var word in body.Split(' '))
        {
            if (word.StartsWith("#"))
                newbody += "[" + word + "]";
            newbody += word;
        }
```

Goal output:

> Example string with a [#hashtag] in it

I also only want it to have A-Z a-z 0-9 and _ stopping at any other character

> Test #H3ll0_W0rld$%Test => Test [#H3ll0_W0rld]$%Test

Other Stack questions try to detect the string and extract it, I would like it work with it and put it back in the string without losing anything that methods such as splitting by certain characters would lose.

Comment: where are there 2 spaces?

Comment: If you mean multiple spaces in a row, then Split will return empty strings and you just have to put them back.   The best way is with `string.Join`.

Comment: You’re looking for regular expressions

Comment: This will be based off user posts so users may type two spaces in their post.

Comment: you are much better off with regex.replace

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use Regex with `#\w+` and `$&`

**Explanation**

- `#` matches the character `#` literally (case sensitive)
- `\w+` matches any word character (equal to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`)
- `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

`$&` Includes a copy of the entire match in the replacement string.

**Example**

```
var input = "asdads sdfdsf #burgers, #rabbits dsfsdfds #sdf #dfgdfg";
var regex = new Regex(@"#\w+");
var matches = regex.Matches(input);
foreach (var match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match);
}
```

or

```
var result = regex.Replace(input, "[$&]" );
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

**Ouput**

```
#burgers
#rabbits
#sdf
#dfgdfg
asdads sdfdsf [#burgers], [#rabbits] dsfsdfds [#sdf] [#dfgdfg]
```

[**Updated Demo here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nS2woO)

[**Another Example**](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%23%5cw%2b&i=Test+%23H3ll0_W0rld%24%25Test&r=%5b%24%26%5d)

Comment: Does this support the second block quote in my question too?

Comment: This only seems to find the hashtags though, how put brackets on each one? Should I find the matches then loop the matches and use a foreach and replace each hashtag with [ + hashtag + ]

Comment: @dan you can use regex replace, ill give you another exmaple

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression: `\#\w*`

```
string pattern = "\#\w*";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
MatchCollection matches = rgx.Matches(input);
```